# restart sequential numbering in access DB for new year

Tags: database, datetime, increment

I have a simple access database that tracks projects.  There's a SLR project number column that i have set up to automatically increment up.  However I would like it to restart numbering back to 1 when the year changes.  I have found several different discussions that talk about this and have tried to modify the code to fit my DB but i keep getting error messages.  My form has fields linked to the underlying table for Start_Date and newLogNum.  I added a button to the form to generate a new number with this code, which i found on another forum and modified to match my table and field names:

```
Private Sub cmdNewLogNum_Click()

      If IsNull(Me.txtStart_Date) Then

       MsgBox "Enter Date to generate number", vbOKOnly

       Me.txtStart_Date.SetFocus

Else

     Me.txtnewLogNum = Nz(DMax("[newLogNum]", "tblSLRTasks", "Year([Start_Date]) = " & Year(Me.[txtStart_Date])), 0) + 1

   End If
End Sub
```

When I try to run this I first get an error message saying "Compile Error: Expected enf of statement" which hilights the second word in my msgbox code.  So i tried removing all but one word withing the quotes within msgbox and then I get a compile error saying Sub or Function not defined for the first use of "Year" in the criteria statement.  Can anyone help me fix this line of code so it will work?  Thanks!

Comment: Most programming languages prefer double quotes like these: "". You seem to have typographic quotes:  “”. See the difference?

Comment: Isn't that jsut a font issue?  I only have one key on my keyboard for double quotes.

Comment: Ok, just tried it and you are right, I copied and pasted and then edited the code so it retained the wrong type of quotes in the vba window.  When I retype them they are correct kind.  Thanks!

Comment: Do you still get the same error?

Comment: Ok the correct quotes fixed the problem with the message box, but now I am still having trouble with setting the criteria for the new log number. Now when I click the button to generate a new log # I get an error message that says the the MS Access DB cannot find the input table 'tblSLRTasks' so it is not creating a new number.  I pasted the updated code in the box above because it didn't fit here.

Comment: Update your question with this new information. Does "tblSLRTasks" exist?

Comment: Yes the table is still there.  It is the source of the data that is in the form I am trying to use to enter projects, so it seems like it must be a problem with my code syntax.

Comment: So I realized that I renamed the table but kept using the old name in the code. seems to be working now

Answer (score 0):

Most programming languages require double quotes like these: "". You seem to have typographic quotes: “”. Microsoft Access will require the first kind of double quotes.

The next step in troubleshooting Access native functions (VBA native functions) is usually to run them piece-by-piece in the Immediate Window. First evaluate `Year([Start_Date])`. Next, evaluate `DMax("[newLogNum]", "tblSLRTasks", "Year([Start_Date])`, etc.